# Client not connecting when using socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I don't know what I'm missing. No error is thrown or anything, it just doesn't connect.

Server side code

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);
// Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Run when client connects
io.sockets.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('New Conncection...')
})

const PORT = 4000 || process.env.PORT;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Client Side Code

```
var io = require('socket.io-client')
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000', {reconnect: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working example:

File structure:

```
.
├── public
│   └── index.html
└── server.js
```

`server.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);
// Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Run when client connects
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New Conncection...');
  io.sockets.emit('event', 'everyone');

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('disconnected');
  });
});

const PORT = 4000 || process.env.PORT;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

`index.html`:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        var socket = io('http://localhost:4000', { reconnection: true });
        socket.on('connect', function() {
          console.log('socket connection success');
        });
        socket.on('event', function(data) {
          console.log('data:', data);
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
          console.log('socket disconnect');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The logs for server-side:

```
Server running on port 4000
New Conncection...
disconnected
New Conncection...
```

The logs for client-side:

```
socket connection success
data: everyone
```